# Laravel 8: Migrations how can i add string that is more than 1k characters?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration, laravel-8

Hello guys I have this migration? and I want the string of the table body up to 1000 characters.
I think the default of characters in a string is 255. I hope you can help me because I need to input more than 700 strings. thanks guys

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->string('editedby');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `longText`

```
$table->longText('body');
```

The `longText` method creates a `LONGTEXT` equivalent column:

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-longText

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->string('name', 1000);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-string